# mock nested properties in mockk

Tags: android, junit, mockk

I have a function which uses a field in `DisplayMetrics` of `Resources` of `Context` class:

```kotlin
fun getIconForDevice(context: Context, iconUrl: String): String {
    val metrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
    var suffix = ""
    //below checks MUST be in this increasing order or it may failed
    if (metrics.densityDpi <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)
        suffix = "-m"
    else if (metrics.densityDpi <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH)
        suffix = "-h"
    else if (metrics.densityDpi <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)
        suffix = "-xh"
    else if (metrics.densityDpi <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH || metrics.densityDpi > DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH)
        suffix = "-xxh"
    val pasvand = iconUrl.substring(iconUrl.lastIndexOf("."))
    val str = iconUrl.substring(0, iconUrl.lastIndexOf(".")) + suffix + pasvand
    return str
}
```

In order to test it, I need to mock `Context` and `metrics.densityDpi` to give it a value.
I'm using **Mockk (1.9.3)** library to do that.

```kotlin
@Test
fun getIconForDevice_ReturnsUrlWithXxhForXxhDisplay() {
    val context: Context = mockk(relaxed = true)
    every { context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi } returns 450
    assertEquals(IconHelper.getIconForDevice(context,
      "https://website.com/image.png"), "https://website.com/image-xxh.png")
}
```

Running the test following error stacktrace is given:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.util.DisplayMetrics

    at ...Resources.getDisplayMetrics(Resources.java)
    at ....IconHelper.getIconForDevice(IconHelper.kt:39)
    at ...IconHelperTest.getIconForDevice_ReturnsUrlWithXxhForXxhDisplay(IconHelperTest.kt:30)
```

The first link refers to `val metrics = context.resources.displayMetrics` line of the actual function

So how can I mock such a nested field in mockk?
`context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi`

Answer (score 2):

Your setup of mocking `Context` and `densityDpi` is correct.

The test fails because you are calling `getIconForDevice` with a new mockk instead of your mocked `Context`.

```kotlin
@Test
fun getIconForDevice_ReturnsUrlWithXxhForXxhDisplay() {
    val context: Context = mockk(relaxed = true)
    every { context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi } returns 450

    // pass in mocked context
    assertEquals(IconHelper.getIconForDevice(context, "https://website.com/image.png"), "https://website.com/image-xxh.png")
}
```

### Update

Regarding your `ClassCastException`, because you are accessing the `DisplayMetrics` first:

```kotlin
val metrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
```

I think you need to separate the mock of `displayMetrics` and `densityDpi`:

```kotlin
@Test
fun getIconForDevice_ReturnsUrlWithXxhForXxhDisplay() {
  val context: Context = mockk(relaxed = true)
  val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics = mockk(relaxed = true) // maybe relaxed is not needed, I just put it here in case
  every { context.resources.displayMetrics } returns displayMetrics
  every { displayMetrics.densityDpi } returns 450

  assertEquals(IconHelper.getIconForDevice(context, "https://website.com/image.png"), "https://website.com/image-xxh.png")
}
```

Comment: That was rookie mistake. Sorry. However, with the correction test fails with a cast exception. I'll update the question

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv no problem, can happen. I updated my answer regarding your `ClassCastException`. Hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.12.0
Run as unit test kotlin 1.5.10

```
    // WORKS
    val context: Context = mockk()
    every { context.resources.displayMetrics } returns DisplayMetrics().apply {

        this.densityDpi = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW
    }
```

ERROR - returns class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class android.util.DisplayMetrics

```
    val context: Context = mockk()
    every { context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi } returns DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW
```

ERROR - returns Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock

```
    val context: Context = mockk()
    val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics = mockk()
    every { context.resources.displayMetrics } returns displayMetrics
    every { displayMetrics.densityDpi } returns DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW
```

Comment: Getting the same

ERROR - returns Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock

Comment: @MitchThornton did you try the snipped in // WORKS ?

Comment: @Ankhha8 It worked for mocking what you answered but I was trying to mock out something slightly different:
 
TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, this, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()

But was running into problems